# An inequality about Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is holomorphic in $B(0,1), \ f(B(0,1)) \subset B(0,1)$

Please show that 
$$
\left|f(z)-\frac{f(0)(1-|z|^2)}{1-|f(0)|^2|z|^2}\right| \le \frac{|z|(1-|f(0)|^2)}{1-|f(0)|^2|z|^2}
$$
I want to construct transformation $T_1,T_2$ and use Schwarz Lemma to $T1 \circ f \circ T2$ to get this inequality. But I don't know how to construct.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We may assume without loss of generality that $\alpha =f(0)$ is real positive.
Fix $r<1$.
We prove that$$
\left|f(re^{i\theta })-\frac{\alpha (1-r^2)}{1-\alpha ^2r^2}\right| \le \frac{r(1-\alpha ^2)}{1-\alpha ^2r^2}\tag{1}
$$for $0\le \theta <2\pi$.
Let $$F(z)=\frac{f(z)-\alpha }{1-\alpha f(z)}.$$ Since $F(0)=0$ and $|F(z)|< 1$, $|F(z)|\le |z|$ by Schwarz lemma. This means the image of $|z|\le r$ by $w=F(z)$ is contained in $|w|\le r$.
Consider $$
T(w)=\frac{w+\alpha r^2}{1+\alpha w}.
$$The mapping $\zeta =T(w)$ mapps $|w|\le r$ to $|\zeta |\le r$ as easily checked. Thus $$\zeta =T(w)=T(F(z))=\frac{(1-\alpha ^2r^2)f(z)-\alpha (1-r^2)}{1-\alpha ^2}
$$mapps $|z|\le r$ to $|\zeta |\le r$.Therefore $$
|T(F(re^{i\theta }))|=\left|\frac{(1-\alpha ^2r^2)f(re^{i\theta })-\alpha (1-r^2)}{1-\alpha ^2}\right|\le r.
$$This is equivalent to ($1$).